# Why is putting the module level code into a function and then calling the function is faster in Python?

Tags: python, function, optimization, module

In Alex Martelli's response to [Making a Python script Object-Oriented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813117/making-a-python-script-object-oriented), he mentions that putting module level code into a function and then calling the function is faster in Python.  Can someone explain why and whether it's true for all implementations of Python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is mostly due to variable look-up.  Looking up a variable in the global scope requires a dictionary look-up.  In contrast, the compiler determines local names statically and references them by index, so no dictionary look up is required.

Note that in Python 2.x the presence of an `exec` statement inside a function will deactivate this optimisation, since names can't be determined statically any more.  In Python 3.x, `exec()` is a regular function, and as such it isn't allowed to change the variables in the local scope.

Comment: So I guess this is true for Jython, IronPython, and PyPy as well?  Do they all implement global scope using the dictionary lookup and local scope using a list?

Comment: @inman320: No, this does not hold for other Python implementations.  In PyPy, there shouldn't be any difference in speed between code at module or function level respectively (they use a JIT compiler).  I don't know how the other implementations perform.