# Why does Python code run faster in a function?

Tags: python, performance, profiling, benchmarking, cpython

```
def main():
    for i in xrange(10**8):
        pass
main()
```

This piece of code in Python runs in  (Note: The timing is done with the time function in BASH in Linux.)

```
real    0m1.841s
user    0m1.828s
sys     0m0.012s
```

However, if the for loop isn't placed within a function,

```
for i in xrange(10**8):
    pass
```

then it runs for a much longer time:

```
real    0m4.543s
user    0m4.524s
sys     0m0.012s
```

Why is this?

Comment: How did you actually do the timing?

Comment: Just an intuition, not sure if it's true: I would guess it's because of scopes. In the function case, a new scope is created (i.e. kind of a hash with variable names bound to their value). Without a function, variables are in the global scope, when you can find lot of stuff, hence slowing down the loop.

Comment: I didn't believe you until I reproduced this. `Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`

Comment: @Scharron That doesn't seem to be it.  Defined 200k dummy variables into the scope without that visibly affecting the running time.

Comment: Alex Martelli wrote a good answer concerning this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1813167/174728

Comment: @Scharron you're half correct. It is about scopes, but the reason it's faster in locals is that local scopes are actually implemented as arrays instead of dictionaries (since their size is known at compile-time).

Comment: @AndrewJaffe The output would suggest linux' `time` command.

Comment: i just tested this snippet in IPython 2.7.5

%timeit "def main(): for i in xrange(10**8): pass; main()"
=> 100000000 loops, best of 3: 16.9 ns per loop
# and
%timeit "for i in xrange(10**8): pass"
=> 100000000 loops, best of 3: 16.6 ns per loop

Answer (score 589, accepted):

You might ask *why* it is faster to store local variables than globals. This is a CPython implementation detail.

Remember that CPython is compiled to bytecode, which the interpreter runs. When a function is compiled, the local variables are stored in a fixed-size array (*not* a `dict`) and variable names are assigned to indexes. This is possible because you can't dynamically add local variables to a function. Then retrieving a local variable is literally a pointer lookup into the list and a refcount increase on the `PyObject` which is trivial.

Contrast this to a global lookup (`LOAD_GLOBAL`), which is a true `dict` search involving a hash and so on. Incidentally, this is why you need to specify `global i` if you want it to be global: if you ever assign to a variable inside a scope, the compiler will issue `STORE_FAST`s for its access unless you tell it not to.

By the way, global lookups are still pretty optimised. Attribute lookups `foo.bar` are the *really* slow ones!

Here is small [illustration](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Local_Variables) on local variable efficiency.

Comment: This also applies to PyPy, up to the current version (1.8 at the time of this writing.)  The test code from the OP runs about four times slower in global scope compared to inside a function.

Comment: @JeremyPridemore, The last sentence of katrielalex'x answer is "By the way, global lookups are still pretty optimised. Attribute lookups foo.bar are the really slow ones!". Isn't he saying that global lookups are optimized and faster, but attribute lookups are really slow?

Comment: @Walkerneo The primary conversation going on here is the comparison between local variable lookups within a function and global variable lookups that are defined at the module level. If you notice in your original comment reply to this answer you said "I wouldn't have thought global variable lookups were faster than local variable property lookups." and they're not. katrielalex said that, although local variable lookups are faster than global ones, even global ones are pretty optimized and faster than attribute lookups (which are different). I don't have enough room in this comment for more.

Comment: @Walkerneo foo.bar is not a local access. It is an attribute of an object. (Forgive the lack of formatting)`def foo_func: x = 5`, `x` is local to a function. Accessing `x` is local. `foo = SomeClass()`, `foo.bar` is attribute access. `val = 5` global is global. As for speed local > global > attribute according to what I've read here. So accessing `x` in `foo_func` is fastest, followed by `val`, followed by `foo.bar`. `foo.attr` isn't a local lookup because in the context of this convo, we're talking about local lookups being a lookup of a variable that belongs to a function.

Comment: Correct. A local variable lookup is a fixed-time pointer. A global lookup is a dict search, but with optimisations (I think the dict code is inlined, for instance). An attribute lookup is just a plain Python dict search.

Comment: @Walkerneo Ah, I think I see where the confusion might lie. An attribute lookup like `foo.bar` is _not_ the same as looking up a variable called `"foo.bar"`; instead, it first looks up the (local) variable called `foo` but then searches for `"bar"` in `foo.__dict__`. It's this second bit that takes time.

Comment: Is there any documentation that global variables are stored in a dict? The other answer links to documentation to STORE_FAST, used to store local variables, which says "Stores TOS into the local co_varnames[var_num]." I don't know what TOS means, but presumably this means the variable is stored in an array. However in the documentation for STORE_NAME, it's not clear a dict is used.  

Also, I don't know anything about CPython, so would all this information apply to normal python?

Comment: @thedoctar have a look at the `globals()` function. If you want more info than that you may have to start looking at the source code for Python. And CPython is just the name for the usual implementation of Python -- so you probably are using it already!

Comment: When you guys talk about "attribute lookups" `foo.bar` being slow, does this include using `self.my_var` inside of a class's methods? If so, then why do people use attribute lookups in classes all the time instead of just using one giant global dictionary?

Comment: Yes, and because most of the time the slight slowness isn't actually important to the running speed of the program.

Comment: "This is possible because you can't dynamically add local variables to a function." What about `locals()[dynamic_expr] = val`?

Comment: @Quelklef: Modifying the `dict` returned by `locals` is [explicitly noted to be unsupported](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals); it can't actually add "real" locals, but the implementation is such that the only way you could dynamically check said "locals" will happen to work, sometimes, on the CPython interpreter; when you first call `locals()` in a function it makes a mirror of the actual locals as a `dict` and caches it; if you call `locals()` again in the same function, you get the same `dict`. But it's not actually resizing the array of "real" locals.

Answer (score 712):

Inside a function, the bytecode is:

```
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              20 (to 23)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (xrange)
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 (100000000)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 22)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  3          19 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   22 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   23 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
```

At the top level, the bytecode is:

```
  1           0 SETUP_LOOP              20 (to 23)
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (xrange)
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 (100000000)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 22)
             16 STORE_NAME               1 (i)

  2          19 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   22 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   23 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
```

The difference is that [`STORE_FAST`](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_FAST) is faster (!) than [`STORE_NAME`](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_NAME).  This is because in a function, `i` is a local but at toplevel it is a global.

To examine bytecode, use the [`dis` module](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html).  I was able to disassemble the function directly, but to disassemble the toplevel code I had to use the [`compile` builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#compile).

Comment: Confirmed by experiment.  Inserting `global i` into the `main` function makes the running times equivalent.

Comment: This answers the question without answering the question :)  In the case of local function variables, CPython actually stores these in a tuple (which is mutable from the C code) until a dictionary is requested (e.g. via `locals()`, or `inspect.getframe()` etc.). Looking up an array element by a constant integer is much faster than searching a dict.

Comment: the variables within functions tend to be on the top of the stack providing quicker access. Global variables are often in heap or a father away segment depending on compiler implementations. So accessing them is slower (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169858/global-memory-management-in-c-in-stack-or-heap)

Comment: @codejammer This is very system dependent.  On a relatively "dumb" microprocessor, it won't care one bit where the memory resides within RAM.

Comment: @gkimsey I agree that it relates heavily to computer architecture. However i noticed that this is the case with general purpose computers that we have

Comment: @gkimsey I agree. Just wanted to share two things i) This behaviour is noted in other programming languages ii) The causal agent is more the architectural side and not the language itself in true sense

Comment: How do you read the bytecode,and from where can you get the bytecode of a function?

Comment: @Pratik see the documentation for the `dis` module: http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html

Comment: @ecatmur Can you tell me how you use the `compile` built in to disassemble the top level code ?

Comment: @manty write `dis.dis(compile('for i in xrange(10**8):\n    pass', 'main.py', 'exec'))`

Comment: @ecatmur you only need to `dis.dis(sourcecode)`, no need to `compile(sourcecode,"main.py",'exec')`(NOTE: Tested on python 3.10.1 only)

Answer (score 49):

Aside from local/global variable store times, **opcode prediction** makes the function faster.

As the other answers explain, the function uses the `STORE_FAST` opcode in the loop. Here's the bytecode for the function's loop:

```
    >>   13 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 22)   # get next value from iterator
         16 STORE_FAST               0 (x)       # set local variable
         19 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13           # back to FOR_ITER
```

Normally when a program is run, Python executes each opcode one after the other, keeping track of the a stack and preforming other checks on the stack frame after each opcode is executed. Opcode prediction means that in certain cases Python is able to jump directly to the next opcode, thus avoiding some of this overhead.

In this case, every time Python sees `FOR_ITER` (the top of the loop), it will "predict" that `STORE_FAST` is the next opcode it has to execute. Python then peeks at the next opcode and, if the prediction was correct, it jumps straight to `STORE_FAST`. This has the effect of squeezing the two opcodes into a single opcode.

On the other hand, the `STORE_NAME` opcode is used in the loop at the global level. Python does ***not*** make similar predictions when it sees this opcode. Instead, it must go back to the top of the evaluation-loop which has obvious implications for the speed at which the loop is executed.

To give some more technical detail about this optimization, here's a quote from the [`ceval.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/45b1ae1ef318/Python/ceval.c#l784) file (the "engine" of Python's virtual machine):

> Some opcodes tend to come in pairs thus making it possible to
>    predict the second code when the first is run.  For example,
>    `GET_ITER` is often followed by `FOR_ITER`. And **`FOR_ITER` is often
>    followed by `STORE_FAST`** or `UNPACK_SEQUENCE`.
>
> Verifying the prediction costs a single high-speed test of a register
>       variable against a constant.  If the pairing was good, then the
>       processor's own internal branch predication has a high likelihood of
>       success, resulting in a nearly zero-overhead transition to the
>       next opcode.  A successful prediction saves a trip through the eval-loop
>       including its two unpredictable branches, the `HAS_ARG` test and the
>       switch-case.  Combined with the processor's internal branch prediction,
>       a successful `PREDICT` has the effect of making the two opcodes run as if
>       they were a single new opcode with the bodies combined.

We can see in the source code for the [`FOR_ITER`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/45b1ae1ef318/Python/ceval.c#l2493) opcode exactly where the prediction for `STORE_FAST` is made:

```C
case FOR_ITER:                         // the FOR_ITER opcode case
    v = TOP();
    x = (*v->ob_type->tp_iternext)(v); // x is the next value from iterator
    if (x != NULL) {                     
        PUSH(x);                       // put x on top of the stack
        PREDICT(STORE_FAST);           // predict STORE_FAST will follow - success!
        PREDICT(UNPACK_SEQUENCE);      // this and everything below is skipped
        continue;
    }
    // error-checking and more code for when the iterator ends normally
```

The `PREDICT` function expands to `if (*next_instr == op) goto PRED_##op` i.e. we just jump to the start of the predicted opcode. In this case, we jump here:

```C
PREDICTED_WITH_ARG(STORE_FAST);
case STORE_FAST:
    v = POP();                     // pop x back off the stack
    SETLOCAL(oparg, v);            // set it as the new local variable
    goto fast_next_opcode;
```

The local variable is now set and the next opcode is up for execution. Python continues through the iterable until it reaches the end, making the successful prediction each time.

The [Python wiki page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/CPythonVmInternals) has more information about how CPython's virtual machine works.

Comment: Minor update: As of CPython 3.6, the savings from prediction go down a bit; instead of two unpredictable branches, there is only one. The change is due to [the switch from bytecode to wordcode](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#optimizations); now all "wordcodes" have an argument, it's just zero-ed out when the instruction doesn't logically take an argument. Thus, the `HAS_ARG` test never occurs (except when low level tracing is enabled both at compile and runtime, which no normal build does), leaving only one unpredictable jump.

Comment: Even that unpredictable jump doesn't happen in most builds of CPython, because of the new ([as of Python 3.1](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.1.html#optimizations), [enabled by default in 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#build-and-c-api-changes)) computed gotos behavior; when used, the `PREDICT` macro is completely disabled; instead most cases end in a `DISPATCH` that branches directly. But on branch predicting CPUs, the effect is similar to that of `PREDICT`, since branching (and prediction) is per opcode, increasing the odds of successful branch prediction.