# Function call execution speed is faster than non-function call

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-internals

Function call will always yield some overhead. But why the code below shows that non-function call is slower.

### Code:

```
import time

def s():
    for i in range(1000000000):
        1 + 1

t = time.time()
s()
print("Function call: " + str(time.time() - t))

t = time.time()
for i in range(1000000000):
    1 + 1
print("Non function call: " + str(time.time() - t))
```

### Output:

```
Function call: 38.39736223220825
Non function call: 60.33238506317139
```

Comment: related: [Python - performance with global variables vs local](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12590058/4279)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might be thinking that since the loop only does `1 + 1`, there shouldn't be much difference. **But**, there's a 'hidden' [assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) here that's commonly forgotten: to the loop variable `i` in your `for` loop. This is the cause of the slowdown.

In functions, this is done with [`STORE_FAST`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_FAST). In the top level, it's done with [`STORE_NAME`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_NAME). The first is faster than the other and, in a loop that runs `1000000000` times, this difference is shown quite clearly.

Remember that the function invocation only *happens once*. So its overhead doesn't really contribute in this specific scenario.

Besides that, all other steps happen once and are pretty much the same. A range is created and its iterator grabbed and the constant `2` is loaded for every iteration.

---

You can always use the [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) to examine the CPython bytecode that is produced for each of these, as @Moses indicated in a comment. For the function `s`, you have:

```
dis.dis(s)
#       snipped for brevity
        >>   10 FOR_ITER                 8 (to 20)
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  3          14 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             16 POP_TOP
             18 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           10
```

While for the top-level version of the loop:

```
dis('for i in range(1000000000): 1+1')
#       snipped for brevity
        >>   10 FOR_ITER                 8 (to 20)
             12 STORE_NAME               1 (i)
             14 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             16 POP_TOP
             18 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           10
```

The main difference between these is in the storing of the iteration value `i`. In functions, it's simply more efficient.

---

To address @Reblochon Masque (now deleted) answer that seems to show no discrepancy between these two when timed with `timeit` in IPython cells.

`timeit` times things by creating a little-function ([named `inner`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/timeit.py#L70)) that stores the statements you pass and executes them for a given number of executions. You can see this if you create a `Timer` object and peek at its `src` attribute (this isn't documented so don't expect it to always be there :-):

```
from timeit import Timer

t = Timer('for i in range(10000): 1 + 1')
print(t.src)
```

This contains the little function that is essentially timed. The previous `print` call prints:

```
def inner(_it, _timer):
    pass
    _t0 = _timer()
    for _i in _it:
        for i in range(10000): 1 + 1
    _t1 = _timer()
    return _t1 - _t0
```

So, in effect, by using `timeit` you have altered the way the look-up for `i` is performed, since it is inside a function it's also done with `STORE_FAST`. Easy pitfall!

<sup><sup>(and if you don't believe me, see `dis.dis(compile(t.src, '', 'exec').co_consts[0])`)</sup></sup>

Comment: can you add some reference to your answer?

Comment: @AmitTripathi `dis.dis(s)` and `dis.dis('for i in range(1000000000): 1 + 1')` is all you need, in Python 3.