# Self written os.walk-alike is much slower then os.walk itself - why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, python-3.6

Unfortunately this code runs slower than "os.walk", but why?

Can it be "for" cycle that causes it to run slowly?

**"Code that works like 'os.walk':** (The "os.walk" function does what it does)

**Note:** *I wrote to improve myself!*:

```
import os, time
from os.path import *

x = ""
y = []
z = []
var = 0

def walk(xew):
    global top, var, x,y,z
    if not var: var = [xew]
    for i in var:
        try:
            for ii in os.listdir(i):
                y.append(ii) if isdir(i+os.sep+ii) else z.append(ii)

            x = top = i
            var = [top+os.sep+i for i in os.listdir(top) if isdir(top+os.sep+i)]         
        except:
            continue
        yield x,y,z
        yield from walk(var)
        var.clear();y.clear();z.clear()
```

**for example**:

*It ends in 2 seconds:*

```
for x,y,z in walk(path):
    print(x)
```

*It is in 0.5 seconds:*

```
for x,y,z in os.walk(path):
    print(x)
```

Comment: Apart from implementation details, definitely check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590058/python-performance-with-global-variables-vs-local if it will affect the performance

Comment: @mfrackowiak: that doesn't account for the big difference, however.

Comment: I would guess anything that takes `os.walk` half a second to walk to be a somewhat large directory tree. Perhaps with some symlinks. OPs implementation follows symlink directories whilst the version in `os` does not by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`os.walk()` doesn't use `os.listdir()`. It uses the much faster [`os.scandir()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir), which provides an iterator with more information per directory entry:

> Using `scandir()` instead of `listdir()` can significantly increase the performance of code that also needs file type or file attribute information, because `os.DirEntry` objects expose this information if the operating system provides it when scanning a directory. All `os.DirEntry` methods may perform a system call, but `is_dir()` and `is_file()` usually only require a system call for symbolic links; `os.DirEntry.stat()` always requires a system call on Unix but only requires one for symbolic links on Windows.

The `os.walk()` code makes heavy use of the `DirEntry.is_dir()` call, which with `os.scandir()` is much cheaper than using `os.isdir()` (which must make separate `os.stat()` calls).

Next, your code is calling `os.isdir()` too often. You are effectively calling it twice for every file entry in your path. You already collected all the subdirectories in `y`, you don't need to test the paths again when re-creating `var`. These extra `isdir()` calls cost you a lot of time.

You also recurse when `var` is *empty* (no further subdirectories), causing you to first wrap the empty list in another list, after which `os.listdir()` throws a `TypeError` exception which your blanket Pokemon-catch-em-all except handler silences.

Next, you should get rid of the global variables, and use proper variable names. `files` and `dirs` would be far clearer names than `y` and `z`. Because you made `y` and `z` globals you are retaining all file and directory names for a given level, and for every first subdirectory on down, you then re-report those same file and directory names as if they are members of those subdirectories. Only when the first leaf of such a directory tree (with no further subdirectories) is reached do the `.clear()` calls on `y` and `z` get executed, leading to very confusing results with repeated filenames.

You can study the [`os.walk()` source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.8/Lib/os.py#L277-L415), but if we simplify it down to only use top-down traversal and no error handling, then it comes down to:

```
def walk(top):
    dirs = []
    nondirs = []

    with os.scandir(top) as scandir_it:
        for entry in scandir_it:
            if entry.is_dir():
                dirs.append(entry.name)
            else:
                nondirs.append(entry.name)

    yield top, dirs, nondirs

    for dirname in dirs:
        new_path = os.path.join(top, dirname) 
        yield from walk(new_path)
```

Note that there are *no global variables used*; there simply is no need for any in this algorithm. There is only a single `os.scandir()` call per directory, and the `dirs` variable is re-used to recurse into subdirectories.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the change to using `os.scandir` (which was a relatively recent work by Giampaolo Rodolà) accounts for something like 20-50% performance improvement and a similar amount of decrease in number of syscalls, however the OP experiences a 200% performance difference. So this is not the only reason, even though it is a significant factor.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta: it depends on the number of files and the number of subdirectories to recurse into as well. We don't know the mix here.

Comment: Yes you are right. The OP should test `os.walk` on the same directory for two different python versions (e.g. python2.7 vs python3.7) and see whether they see a significant difference or not... if there is not a huge difference then an other factor is at play, if the difference is big then it's probably just the change to `os.scandir`.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta: here it is the doubled `os.isdir()` calls that cover the remaining time differences.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for your answer, my purpose was to understand why this code was slow, and thanks to you,i learned something to satisfy myself!

Answer (score 0):

This code it works almost as fast as `os.walk`!

```
import os, time
from os.path import *

def walk(top):
    x = top;y=[];z=[]
    try:
        for i in os.listdir(top):
            y.append(i) if isdir(top+os.sep+i) else z.append(i)
    except: pass
    else:
        yield x,y,z
        for q in y: yield from walk(top+os.sep+q)
```