# Limit of performance benefit gained in Python from using local variables instead of global variables?

Tags: python, performance, micro-optimization

I came upon a question which says that [Python code runs faster in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241523/why-does-python-code-run-faster-in-a-function). So I thought that breaking code down into as many parts as I can will be the faster approach. But when timing some functions I found that it wasn't really correct.

I won't post the code here as [it is currently placed for review at codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28700/is-there-a-more-efficient-way-for-code-reuse-in-python-largest-prime-factor). I am still figuring out the best way to do timing as that [code is also placed for review at codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28373/is-this-the-proper-way-of-doing-timing-analysis-of-many-test-cases-in-python-or) and I am not getting many answer despite a bounty.

I figured out that the performance benefit cannot be infinite and there has to be a limit where breaking functions down would stop giving performance benefit.

So what is the the limit where performance benefit stops by breaking Python code into various functions? From the point of performance, when is breaking code into functions no longer useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that code runs faster in a function than in the global scope because of access times. A function has its own local scope which is implemented as an array, whereas the global scope is really just a dictionary. Arrays are accessed faster than dicts and this is happening under the hood, on the C level.

This doesn't imply that breaking the code up into many functions will make it quicker, it only implies that moving code from global to inside *a* function will improve access times, which might result in an overall boost in speed.

Even if you were to shove all your code inside one function just for the sake of using local scope instead of global, it doesn't guarantee a performance improvement, which can only be determined by actually profiling the code. This is because function calls have a relatively high overhead in Python which might dwarf any performance gain from faster local access times.

There's a lot of info on the page at the [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241523/why-does-python-code-run-faster-in-a-function) you provided that confirms this.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, that performance boost only applies when global variables are moved into a local scope of a function, as it improves their access time. Further breaking your code down into more functions won't provide any similar boost.