# What is the style guideline for if __name__ == '__main__'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, coding-style

I understand the purpose of it, however I was wondering what is the most pythonic way to use `if __name__ == '__main__'` ?

I'm divided between putting all my code in a `main()` function and calling it like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Or not bothering with that and just writing all top-level code there:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # all top-level code...
```

Comment: Disagree with the close votes here. This is not opinion-based if the answerer can provide evidence for why one way is better than the other as in the answers Ismail Badawi links to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write all the code under the `__name__` guard, you can never re-use that code. If on the other hand you put the code in a `main()` function, you can always import that function elsewhere and call it.

You'd use this for console scripts registered in your `setup.py` when packaging your project with setuptools, for example. That way you can test your script without installing it first, *and* run it as a installed script (which will add dependencies to `sys.path` before calling your `main()` function).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if one is more idiomatic than the other, but one reason to put everything in a `main` function and call it is that local variable lookups are faster than global variable lookups (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241523/why-does-python-code-run-faster-in-a-function) for an explanation).

Comment: The difference is minimal, certainly for a console script where the code is run just once. It shouldn't be a big concern for 99% of the use cases.

Answer (score -2):

Disclaimer: I only know a little Python from CodeAcademy.

I would go for making the main function, and then calling it. It puts your code together into a "group". JavaScript does almost the same thing, but they call it modules. They make the function, and then call it right afterward.

JavaScript example

```
(function() {
    // Stuff here
})();
```

Comment: This hasn't got anything to do how the code is grouped though.