# locals().update(dictionary) doesn't add all the variables

Tags: python, locals

I have been loading variables using dictionary objects, but the values get updated.  What am I missing here?

```
assert "run_LMM" in all_variables.keys()
locals().update(all_variables)
assert "run_LMM" in locals()
```

The last line is were I get an assertion error.  What's going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour, by [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals):

> The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

I think, one of the reasons for that is that whether a variable is global or local is defined during the function compilation, so that in:

```
def func():
    locals()['val'] = 1
    print val
```

the last statement always reads from the global variable, since the local variable is not declared. So, ability to add locals dynamically would make life harder.

Comment: @CharlieParker I don't think so. What's your use case?

Comment: my use case is to replicate what matlab's load function is https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html , just load variables to the namespace seamlessly and cleanly.

Comment: @CharlieParker no, that's definitely not possible, you will need some object or dict to serve as a namespace.

Comment: why does one need a dict in the middle to work as a namespace? thats the part I don't understand, things are already dumped in python (in a dictionary), why not just put them in real dictionary of namespace python is using anyway. Why add this extra data structure in the middle?

Comment: First reason is, as I mentioned in the answer, the list of the local variables is defined during the function compilation to make access optimisation possible. Second, and more important, is that Python is a generic programming language, and creating local variables dynamically is a lot of potential pain for static checkers, maintainers etc. Third, as Python saying goes, "explicit is better than implicit".

Comment: last question. Intuitively, how does the "pre-compilation" of the function make things more efficient? In what sense is it more efficient and why? Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: I think, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11241523/770830) has few very good answers explaining exactly that.