# Python is not searching the locals namespace

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-internals

I'm trying to import a function from another module; however, I can't use `import` because the module's name needs looking up in a list.

If I try to call the imported function `ExampleFunc` normally I get:

```
NameError: global name 'ExampleFunc' is not defined
```

However; if I explicitly tell python to look in locals, it finds it.

---

File module.py

```
def ExampleFunc(x):
    print x
```

File code.py

```
def imprt_frm(num,nam,scope):
    for key, value in __import__(num,scope).__dict__.items():
        if key==nam:
            scope[key]=value

def imprt_nam(nam,scope):
    imprt_frm("module",nam,scope)

def MainFunc(ary):
    imprt_nam("ExampleFunc",locals())

    #return ExampleFunc(ary)            #fails
    return locals()["ExampleFunc"](ary) #works

MainFunc("some input")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [locals().update(dictionary) doesn't add all the variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197720/locals-updatedictionary-doesnt-add-all-the-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `locals()` dictionary is but a *reflection* of the actual locals array. You cannot add new names to the locals through it, nor can you alter existing locals.

It is a dictionary created on demand from the actual frame locals, and is one-way only. From the [`locals()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals):

> **Note**: The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

Function locals are highly optimised and determined at compile time, Python builds on not being able to alter the known locals dynamically at runtime.

Rather than try and stuff into locals directly, you can return the one object from the dynamic import. Use the [`importlib` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) rather than `__import__` here:

```
import importlib

def import_frm(module_name, name):
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
    return getattr(module, name)
```

then just assign to a local name:

```
def MainFunc(ary):
    ExampleFunc = import_from('module' , 'ExampleFunc')
    ExampleFunc(ary)
```

Comment: then why when I add something to globals() in the same way does it work?

Comment: @undeadherbs: because `globals()` is not such a reflection. Locals is highly optimised for the frame.

Comment: @undeadherbs what's local and what's not is defined during the function compilation. Allowing changing that dynamically would prevent the optimization and allow for some other surprises.