# Global lookup vs local lookup: no performance difference in the ipython notebook?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope, global-variables, jupyter-notebook

So I was reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241523/why-does-python-code-run-faster-in-a-function/11241708#11241708) where the OP shows significant performance differences between the function scope and the global scope (~2x difference). I got excited and tried to reproduce the OP's results in two ways.

#### 1. python script + terminal's `time` command

Function

```
def main():
    for i in xrange(10**8):
        pass
main()

real    0m2.040s
user    0m2.028s
sys 0m0.011s
```

Global

```
for i in xrange(10**8):
    pass

real    0m4.710s
user    0m4.699s
sys 0m0.010s
```

The second version is twice slower, which was expected.

#### 2. ipython notebook

Function:

```
%%timeit
def main():
    for i in xrange(10**8):
        pass
main()
1 loops, best of 3: 2.15 s per loop
```

Global:

```
%%timeit
for i in xrange(10**8):
    pass
1 loops, best of 3: 2.14 s per loop
```

The two versions now show the same performance! What happened?

Comment: The second version also runs in a local scope, you can verify this by accessing `i`(will raise `NameError`) after the timeit call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timeit` runs *all* tests in a *local* namespace. The only difference in your case is that you added a function call, but both versions run with local names.

See the [`inner` function template](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/timeit.py#l80) in the `timeit` module source; `%(stmt)s` is the code being repeatedly tested to get a good average time per execution.