# Python for loop performance in global space vs inside a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've been trying to understand Python for loop performance, here I found that for loop with same iterations in global space is taking much time compared with one inside a function.

```
import time

MAX_NUM = 50000000

# Running for loop in global space
start = time.time()

for i in xrange(MAX_NUM):
    pass

print time.time() - start


# Running th same kind of loop within a function
def foo():
    for i in xrange(MAX_NUM):
        pass

start = time.time()
foo()
print time.time() - start
```

When I execute this I've witnessed a huge difference in execution times.

```
2.00527501106
0.811304092407
```

I'm wondering that what makes this huge difference in execution time? how for loop performance affects from global space to write inside a function?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the disassembled bytecode?

Comment: this is really just a guess, but i think python might know that foo doesn't actually do anything so i can just skip it, while it has to run the global stuff.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241523/why-does-python-code-run-faster-in-a-function

Comment: @NeilLocketz If that's true, `0.8` is an awfully long time to do nothing.

Comment: @Barmar, this is true. Also why i said its a guess xD

Comment: @Barmer : Not yet, but I've been going through Python source code to find how different name spaces affects performance.