# global vs. local namespace performance difference

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, optimization

Why is it that executing a set of commands in a function:

```
def main():
    [do stuff]
    return something
print(main())
```

will tend to run `1.5x` to `3x` times faster in python than executing commands in the top level:

```
[do stuff]
print(something)
```

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that this claim can be tested and investigated?

Comment: This really depends what that "stuff" is

Comment: Other than some code where the claimed speeds occur, how do you actually time it?

Comment: @Reti43 from time import time ...  
start = time() ..... finish = time().. elapsed = start-finish

Comment: @user119264 Thats really poor methodology. Because of the short timeframes, to test code speeds you need to use 1000s of tests using a library like `timeit` to get any meaningful results. A single result code be off because another resource hungry operation in another executable was running at the same time.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241523/why-does-python-code-run-faster-in-a-function

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The difference does indeed **greatly** depend on what "do stuff" actually does and **mainly** on how many times it accesses names that are defined/used. Granted that the code is similar, there is a fundamental difference between these two cases:

- In functions, the byte code for loading/storing names is done with **[`LOAD_FAST`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_FAST)**/**[`STORE_FAST`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_FAST)**.
- In the top level scope (i.e module), the same commands are performed with **[`LOAD_NAME`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_NAME)**/**[`STORE_NAME`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_NAME)** which are more sluggish.

This can be viewed in the following cases, *I'll be using a `for` loop to make sure that lookups for variables defined is performed multiple times*.

**Function and `LOAD_FAST/STORE_FAST`:**

We define a simple function that does some really silly things:

```
def main():
    b = 20
    for i in range(1000000): z = 10 * b 
    return z
```

Output generated by **[`dis.dis`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html#dis.Bytecode.dis)**:

```
dis.dis(main)
# [/snipped output/]

             18 GET_ITER
        >>   19 FOR_ITER                16 (to 38)
             22 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
             25 LOAD_CONST               3 (10)
             28 LOAD_FAST                0 (b)
             31 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             32 STORE_FAST               2 (z)
             35 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           19
        >>   38 POP_BLOCK

# [/snipped output/]
```

The thing to note here is the `LOAD_FAST/STORE_FAST` commands at the offsets `28` and `32`, these are used to access the `b` name  used in the `BINARY_MULTIPLY` operation and store the `z` name, respectively. As their byte code name implies, *they are the fast version* of the `LOAD_*/STORE_*` family.

---

**Modules and `LOAD_NAME/STORE_NAME`:**

Now, let's look at the output of `dis` for our module version of the previous function:

```
# compile the module
m = compile(open('main.py', 'r').read(), "main", "exec")

dis.dis(m)
# [/snipped output/]

             18 GET_ITER
        >>   19 FOR_ITER                16 (to 38)
             22 STORE_NAME               2 (i)
             25 LOAD_NAME                3 (z)
             28 LOAD_NAME                0 (b)
             31 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             32 STORE_NAME               3 (z)
             35 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           19
        >>   38 POP_BLOCK

# [/snipped output/]
```

Over here we have multiple calls to `LOAD_NAME/STORE_NAME`, *which*, as mentioned previously, *are more sluggish commands to execute*.

In this case, *there is going to be a clear difference in execution time*, mainly because Python must evaluate `LOAD_NAME/STORE_NAME` and `LOAD_FAST/STORE_FAST` multiple times (due to the `for` loop I added) and, as a result, the overhead introduced each time the code for each byte code is executed *will accumulate*.

Timing the execution 'as a module':

```
start_time = time.time()
b = 20 
for i in range(1000000): z = 10 *b
print(z)
print("Time: ", time.time() - start_time)
200
Time:  0.15162253379821777
```

Timing the execution as a function:

```
start_time = time.time()
print(main())
print("Time: ", time.time() - start_time)
200
Time:  0.08665871620178223
```

If you `time` loops in a smaller `range` (for example `for i in range(1000)`) you'll notice that the 'module' version is faster. This happens because the overhead introduced by needing to call function `main()` is larger than that introduced by `*_FAST` vs `*_NAME` differences. So it's largely relative to the amount of work that is done.

So, the real culprit here, and the reason why this difference is evident, is the `for` loop used. *You generally have `0` reason to ever put an intensive loop like that one at the top level of your script. Move it in a function and avoid using global variables*, it is designed to be more efficient.

---

You can take a look at the code executed for each of the byte code.  I'll link the source for the [`3.5`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip) version of Python here even though I'm pretty sure [`2.7`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7) doesn't differ much. Bytecode evaluation is done in [`Python/ceval.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/ceval.c) specifically in function [`PyEval_EvalFrameEx`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/ceval.c#l797):

- [`LOAD_FAST source`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/ceval.c#l1369) - [`STORE_FAST source`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/ceval.c#l1389)
- [`LOAD_NAME source`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/ceval.c#l2348) - [`STORE_NAME source`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/ceval.c#l2214)

As you'll see, the `*_FAST` bytecodes simply get the value stored/loaded using a [*`fastlocals` local symbol table contained inside frame objects*](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Include/frameobject.h#l23).