# Function is slower in separate file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a following issue, there is a function to read a big file(few Mb), the content looks like:

```
0x05 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xCF 0x00 0x00 0x00 ; ..........
0xCF 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x22 0x00 0x00 0x00 ; ......"...
0x51 0x84 0x07 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x01 0x00 ; ..Q.......
```

My function has to read only the hex values, and to ignore ";" with following characters till the end of line.

Data from the first line what I need is

"0x05 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xCF 0x00 0x00 0x00 "

I tried two methods, one is with a separate file with this function

```
def ReadFileAsList(fileName):

    fileName = "2Output.txt"
    fileContentStr = ""
    with open(fileName,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            fileContentStr += line.split(';')[0]

    fileContentList = fileContentStr.split()
    return fileContentList
```

and the second method, when these line are directly in my main .py file

```
fileName = "2Output.txt"
fileContentStr = ""
with open(fileName,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        fileContentStr += line.split(';')[0]

fileContentList = fileContentStr.split()
```

The second method is very fast, the first(with the separate function in a separate file) is very slow, what am I missing? 
Thanks for any hint

Comment: In absence of any other culprits, something tells me you *might* be missing out on the optimization CPython does when concatenating strings with `+=` in the function case. I don't remember the actual circumstances that cause that optimization to be disabled. Try creating a list of the strings returning that to see if the difference is still there.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard It helped, thanks

Comment: Under you `with open` line, you could build you list of trimmed lines using a list comprehension like `fileContentList = [line.split(';')[0] for line in f]`

Comment: how do you import the first script and call the method?

Comment: I offer you to read this if you work with large texts https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/

Comment: @BradCampbell my function "ReadFileAsList" is in Functions.py file, in my main.py file I tried two options, 

    `import Functions`
    `ReadFileAsList("filename.txt")`

and the other one
    `from Functions import ReadFileAsList`
    `ReadFileAsList("fileName.txt")`


I know that I did a mistake in my post that I don't use the passed filename to the function, but I think it doesn't play any role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is faster to store local variables than it is for global variables. Local variables are stored in a fixed-sized array, where as global variables are stored in a true dictionary.

Here is a link to a more in-depth [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241523/why-does-python-code-run-faster-in-a-function)